Azure HTTP Trigger - How to extract query parameter value from input binding- cosmosDB
I am following this example, but need to log id from query parameters
The input is
const cosmosInput = input.cosmosDB({
    databaseName: 'ToDoItems',
    collectionName: 'Items',
    id: '{id}',
    partitionKey: '{partitionKeyValue}',
    connectionStringSetting: 'CosmosDBConnection', });

When used as
const toDoItem = context.extraInputs.get(cosmosInput);

the cosmosInput object is json
{
  "databaseName": "demo",
  "containerName": "todo",
  "id": "{id}",
  "partitionKey": "{partitionKeyValue}",
  "connection": "CosmosDBConnection",
  "type": "cosmosDB",
  "name": "cosmosDBInputdc9624d5bb"
}

To pull id, cosmosInput.id comes like {id} and not the actual value from url. So this is not the option.
How to get the real value supplied via URL query parameters?
http://localhost:7071/api/storageOutBinding?id=172&partitionKeyValue=6


FYI - Nobody is "stealing" anything (I'm not even sure what you mean by that) . And people don't have to justify why they up/downvote questions and answers.

To pass value of id and partitionKey in query. you need to use {Query.id} and {Query.partitionkey} as mentioned in the document you are following.
This worked for me.
I have added this in my code to get id value from query
const Id = request.query.get('id');
context.log(`id value is; ${Id}`)


httpTrigger1.js:
const { app, input } = require('@azure/functions');

const cosmosInput = input.cosmosDB({
    databaseName: 'ToDoList',
    containerName: 'Items',
    id: '{Query.id}',
    partitionKey: '{Query.partitionKey}',
    connection: 'CosmosDBConnection'
    
});

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    extraInputs: [cosmosInput],
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);
        const Id = request.query.get('id');
        context.log(`id value is; ${Id}`)
        
        const toDoItem = context.extraInputs.get(cosmosInput);
        if (!toDoItem) {
            return {
                status: 404,
                body: 'ToDoList item not found',
            };
        } else {
            return {
                body: `Found ToDoList item, Message=${toDoItem.message}`,
            };
        }
    },
});



DB data:
{
    "id": "1",
    "partitionKey": "10",
    "message": "Hello, This data is from query string"
}


OUTPUT:



Url works for Query.id or id. I want to print only the id value.

You can use ${toDoItem.id}

I want to log the input ( not output) , if search fails. It should be captured in a const for use than just console.log

@KrisSwat Use const Id = request.query.get('id');

that is the answer. - request.query.get('id') - just found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-javascript.

@NaveenSharma  I can say only the edit part is the answer . If you can remove all other additional information, then it looks perfect to accept as an answer

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
